# TCP /SMPP connection status JAVA

Tags: java, tcp, eof, tcpdump, smpp

I have developed an ESME adhering to SMPP, however when reading the pdu length in the header (the first 4 bytes) I sometimes get an EOF exception. 
I read the first 4 bytes with the readint method of the datainputstream class.

I suspect the Smpp server is closing the connection however while using tcpdump and then reading it with wireshark there is no "FIN" in originating from the server or my end.

So it must be closing abruptly, are there any tools i can use to clearly show that the TCP connection was closed abruptly on there end.

I came across tcpmon not sure it can do what i need though.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are the PDUs you've exchanged with the SMPP Server before getting that EOF ? any chance to see a pcap file ?

Comment: I would like to add the pcap file however it has sensitive info in it. Any idea what i should look out for?

Comment: An EOF may result of a corrupt data transfert between client and server where one of these can be misleading with the protocol, so you may look at the responses of each PDU you sent to the SMSC, you'll probably get an error response with details